# How can I ignore updating some required fields but update some others with a "PUT" request while developing a Web Api in .Net Core environment?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am trying to develop a Web API which have the features like login-register-updateuser. I want a user to fill the required fields such as E-mail, Password and ConfirmPassword while registering as required fields. User does not have to fill the fields such as FirstName,LastName,Addresss etc. But if user wants to add this fields(FirstName,LastName,Addresss)  later, he/she would be able to do this with Update feature. I am using "PUT" request on POSTMAN and giving FirstName,LastName,Address etc. as JSON. When I send my request I get response as "System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'password')"  My question is how can I ignore or disable these required fields while updating a user?

This my  UpdateUserAync method in controller.

```
       [HttpPut("{id}")]

        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUserAync(string id,[FromBody] UpdateViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               
                var result = await _userService.UpdateUserAsync(id,model);
                if (result.IsSuccess)
                    return Ok(result);
                return BadRequest(result);


            }
            return BadRequest("Some Properties are not valid!"); //Status 400

        }
```

This is UpdateViewModel.cs

```
public class UpdateViewModel
{
    public string NewEmail { get; set; }
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

This is RegisterViewModel class

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
       
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
      
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
       
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
      
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string NickName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the UserService.cs where I am updating the user records.

```
 public async Task<UserManagerResponse> UpdateUserAsync([FromRoute] string id ,UpdateViewModel model)
    {
       
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user == null)

            throw new NullReferenceException("Update model is null");

        user.Email = model.NewEmail;
        user.UserName = model.NewEmail;
        user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
        user.LastName = model.LastName;
        user.NickName = model.NickName;
        user.Address = user.Address;
        var password = model.NewPassword;
        var passwordHashed = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, password); 
        user.PasswordHash = passwordHashed;
        var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //TODO: Send an confirmation email
            return new UserManagerResponse
            {
                Message = "User records updated Successfully",
                IsSuccess = true,
                Errors = result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description)
            };

        }
        return new UserManagerResponse
        {
            Message = "User records didnot Updated!",
            IsSuccess = false,
            Errors = result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description)
        };

    }
```

This is the screen shot from POSTMAN
[image]

Comment: handling this on the server-side only is easy but if you have *client-side validation* as well, you will need a custom client-side validation to sync between server-side & client-side. Basically, when you have the *password* field in both use cases (create & update), that field somehow must be required only when creating (not when updating). One trick is try loading a dummy password into your view, the post back will need to ignore it if updating.

Comment: actually if you support the style of PUT or PATCH, you should create different view models with different endpoints for different operations. Trying to put all in one endpoint of course will be more complicated to support scenarios like this.

Comment: Have a look at HTTP `PATCH` verb as @King suggested

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50216166/413032

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
 if (user == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Update model is null");

 if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.NewEmail) )   user.Email=model.NewEmail;
  if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName) )   user.Name=model.NewEmail;    
       ....and so on

 _userManager.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
 var result = await _userManager.SaveChangesAsync();
if(result >0) ....success
```

and change your action UpdateUserAync by removing  if (ModelState.IsValid) and validate manually or keep it and check what properties are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class a
{
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUserAync(string id,[FromBody] UpdateViewModel model)
    {
        // Check if Model null check from request body has been parsed correctly
        if (model == null) 
        {
         string reasonPhrase = "Model request cannot be sent as null.";
         return BadRequest(reasonPhrase);
        }
        else
        {
            //Check if User Model Data Correcly
            var userRs = await _userService.CheckUserAsync(id);
            if(userRs != null)
            {
                var result = await _userService.UpdateUserAsync(id,model);
                if (result.IsSuccess)
                {
                    return Ok(result);
                }
                return BadRequest(result);
            }
            
            return BadRequest("Some Properties are not valid!", userRs); //Status 400
        }
    }
}
```

**User Manager Class**

```
public class UserManager
{
    private readonly UserRepository _userService;

    public UserManager(UserRepository userService)
    {
        this._userService = userService;
    }

    public async Task<UserModel> UpdateUserAync(string id)
    {
        var userData=await this._userService.GetSingleUserAsync(id);

        if(userData != null)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userData.Passord))
            {
                //Call Hash Method
            }

        }
        return userData;
    }
}
```

Here you may need to do a check on the Model and Database side before changing the password.
If the model does not come null, maybe the Database is null and it may be squashing.